# Jssor Carousel with image caption

Tags: jquery-plugins, jssor

The carousel slider pretty much does what I need out of the box.  I just need to show a caption under each image.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can add any content to each slide. Please see following example.

```
        <div>
            <img u="image" src="../img/ancient-lady/005.jpg" />
            <div style="position: absolute; top: 60px; left: 25px; width: 100px; height: 30px;text-align:center;line-height:30px;background:#fff;">
                any content
            </div>
        </div>
```

Reference http://www.jssor.com/development/define-slides-html-code.html